# Possibility of adding libraries to android architecture

Tags: android

I got some doubts regarding the Android OS.

My question is, there are certain libraries and framework specified in the Android Architecture. So is there any possibility to add any other libraries based on my requirements? If yes, how do you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Android SDK is used to develop applications, it is not possible to build libraries.

Although Android library projects can be created but they are compile time in nature. Meaning that libraries are packaged with the APK. If library project is used in multiple applications, each APK will have library classes packaged within it.

More about [library projects](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject).

Answer (score 0):

For add new libraries to your application just right click on the application and select the Properties and in that select JavaBuildPath from left side of the panel in that 4 tabs are available ,select the libraries tab from that and selct addJars from right side of the panel .

First you  copy and paste the library whatever you want and paste it in assets folder of the application.And then add that jar file to your application from assets using above process